# Rails - slice string and rails path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do some string slice. Right now i have something like this:

```
@str = '/images00.someother.path_to_.image.jpg'   ///my spliced string
```

When i do this:

```
@new_string = @str[1..@str.length]
```

i thought that i will have string like:

```
'images00.someother.path_to_.image.jpg'
```

but no... rails put in url path to images, so the output is:

```
<img src='/images/images00.someother.path_to_.image.jpg'>
```

when i slice more it looks like 'images/ages01... etc.

How can i remove this default path but only for this action in controller?

VIEW:

```
<% @array.each do |a| %>
<%= image_tag(a, :id => 'image_' %>
```

Comment: Can you paste all the relevant bit of code: view fragment creating image tag + used there variable's declaration?

Comment: i understand that image_tag put /images/ path to it .. hm

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you don't want the "/images" to appear

just remove the

```
@new_string = @str[1..@str.length]
```

if you pass the path with a starting slash rails won't add the default image path

so the output would be

```
<img src='/images00.someother.path_to_.image.jpg'>
```

which is the images00.someother.path_to_.image.jpg in your public directory

Comment: i know that, but images doesnt show when there is slash '/images00'

Comment: It have something to do with the path that your images are saved. if there is a image in your public folder like public/image.jpg then <img src='/image.jpg'> should show it. unless the image file premisions won't allow the server to read it.

Comment: this image is not in my server. I put url-s to array and then with image_tag try to show it - this problem is only when i take images from one site so i will drop this problem. They make some strange path to it and as i see also with redirect soo problem is not worth sacrifice, but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing in production mode, rails by default don't serve the static files.
You should change it on `config/environments/production.r`b the line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

As long as the question is missing some details, it might help :)